Problem loading new instance of standalone when changing routes
With the following snip-it code I can load and execute all the child components. However when I click on component: CreateInvNoDateComponent and then do something it works properly. When I click on another component in a different route I can execute it properly. But when I go back  to component CreateInvNoDateComponent and enter a new supplier, it seems the be executing the original instance. Can I either load a new instance, or destroy an instance when exiting.
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>

   import { enableProdMode }               from '@angular/core';
   import { DatePipe }                     from '@angular/common';
   import { environment }                  from './environments/environment';
   import { provideRouter }                from '@angular/router';
   import { bootstrapApplication }         from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { AppComponent }                 from '@app/app.component';
   // Main.ts
   if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
   }
   bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {

   providers: [ 
    baseProvider,              
    provideRouter([             
       {path: 'endofmonth', 
          loadChildren: () => 
          import('./app/endofmonth/endofmonth_routing.module')
               .then( m => m.EndOfMonthRoutingModule) },            
       { path: 'transetc',
          loadChildren: () =>           
      
     import('./app/transactionsetc/transactionsetc_routing.module')
            .then( m => m.TransEtcRoutingModule) },
        ...................,      
      ],
      withRouterConfig({
           paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
           onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        }), 
      ),   
      DatePipe  
    ]
    }) .catch(err => console.log('path requested ' + err)); here

    // Inside of transactionsetc/transactionsetc_routing.module'
    const routes: Routes =  [
    {  path: '',  
       component: LandingTransetcComponent,
        children: [
       ...........
      {  path: 'invnodate',component : CreateInvNoDateComponent }  ,
       ............  
      ]
     }]    

     @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
     })
     export class TransEtcRoutingModule { }

     // Inside of endofmonth_routing.module
     const routes: Routes =  [
      {  path: '',  
        component: LandingEomComponent,
        children: [
          {  path: 'closeperiod', component : ClosePeriodComponent },
          {  path: 'import', component : ImportFrmBankComponent },        
        ]
      }]   

      @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
      })
      export class EndOfMonthRoutingModule { }


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated
